How to make numlock permanently on in XFCE and switch it on permanently without root?
I am using FastX3, proprietary solution to connect to the Xfce desktop session from Windows. Normally in Windows I have numlock on and on start it is also the case in remote XFCE.
When I do however click in Windows environment and then return to XFCE, numlock is turned off and I can not reenable it pressing numlock key in XFCE. I know that this is probably some error of FastX3 how it handles Windows Linux interplay.
I need a fix, I don't have access to root of target machine.
Is there a way how I can as a normal user turn the num lock on by command?
Is there a way to tell XFCE as normal user I never want to turn numlock off?

Sound like Windows is exiting dirty and holding control. I suggest you ask the FastX3 people if they have a fix.
